# Save relation in @ManyToMany in typeORM overwrites previous entry

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, typeorm

I have made a follower system using `typeorm/mysql` and `nodejs/express`.

Save logic:

```
router.post("/subscriptions", async (req, res) => {
  const currentUserId = Number(req.headers.userid);
  const userToFollowId = req.body.userToFollowId;

  const userRepository = getRepository(User);

  try {
    let user;
    let userToFollow;

    user = await userRepository.findOneOrFail(currentUserId);
    userToFollow = await userRepository.findOneOrFail(userToFollowId);

    if (user && userToFollow) {
      user.followers = [...(user?.followers || []), userToFollow];
      await userRepository.save(user);
      res.status(201).send("Followed");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

`@User` Entity which has self referencing relation:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  name!: string;

  @Column()
  email!: string;

  @Column()
  password!: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Post, (post) => post.user)
  posts!: Post[];

  @OneToMany(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.user)
  comments!: Comment[];

  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.following, { cascade: true })
  @JoinTable()
  followers!: User[];

  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.followers)
  following!: User[];

  @Column({
    default: () => "NOW()",
  })
  createdAt!: Date;

  @Column({
    default: () => "NOW()",
  })
  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt!: Date;
}
```

Let's say `curentUserId` is 5 and `userToFollow` ID is 6. It will be saved to the database successfully. The problem occurs when I try to save another entry by using same `currentUserId`of 5 and `userToFollow` some other ID (for example 7), in this case previous entry in database:
User `5` follows user with the ID of `6` will be `overwritten` to:
User `5` follows user with the ID of `7`

Here is the query when I save it for the first time:

```
query: SELECT `User`.`id` AS `User_id`, `User`.`name` AS `User_name`, `User`.`email` AS `User_email`, `User`.`password` AS `User_password`, `User`.`createdAt` AS `User_createdAt`, `User`.`updatedAt` AS `User_updatedAt` FROM `user` `User` WHERE `User`.`id` IN (?) -- PARAMETERS: [5]
query: SELECT `User`.`id` AS `User_id`, `User`.`name` AS `User_name`, `User`.`email` AS `User_email`, `User`.`password` AS `User_password`, `User`.`createdAt` AS `User_createdAt`, `User`.`updatedAt` AS `User_updatedAt` FROM `user` `User` WHERE `User`.`id` IN (?) -- PARAMETERS: ["6"]
query: SELECT `User`.`id` AS `User_id`, `User`.`name` AS `User_name`, `User`.`email` AS `User_email`, `User`.`password` AS `User_password`, `User`.`createdAt` AS `User_createdAt`, `User`.`updatedAt` AS `User_updatedAt` FROM `user` `User` WHERE `User`.`id` IN (?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: [5,6]
query: SELECT `User_followers_rid`.`userId_1` AS `userId_1`, `User_followers_rid`.`userId_2` AS `userId_2` FROM `user` `user` INNER JOIN `user_followers_user` `User_followers_rid` ON (`User_followers_rid`.`userId_1` = ? AND `User_followers_rid`.`userId_2` = `user`.`id`) OR (`User_followers_rid`.`userId_1` = ? AND `User_followers_rid`.`userId_2` = `user`.`id`)  ORDER BY `User_followers_rid`.`userId_2` ASC, `User_followers_rid`.`userId_1` ASC -- PARAMETERS: [5,6]
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO `user_followers_user`(`userId_1`, `userId_2`) VALUES (?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: [5,6]
query: COMMIT
```

And this is second one where I think the problem occurs (please note the `DELETE` part):

```
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO `user_followers_user`(`userId_1`, `userId_2`) VALUES (?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: [5,6]
query: COMMIT
query: SELECT `User`.`id` AS `User_id`, `User`.`name` AS `User_name`, `User`.`email` AS `User_email`, `User`.`password` AS `User_password`, `User`.`createdAt` AS `User_createdAt`, `User`.`updatedAt` AS `User_updatedAt` FROM `user` `User` WHERE `User`.`id` IN (?) -- PARAMETERS: [5]
query: SELECT `User`.`id` AS `User_id`, `User`.`name` AS `User_name`, `User`.`email` AS `User_email`, `User`.`password` AS `User_password`, `User`.`createdAt` AS `User_createdAt`, `User`.`updatedAt` AS `User_updatedAt` FROM `user` `User` WHERE `User`.`id` IN (?) -- PARAMETERS: ["7"]
query: SELECT `User`.`id` AS `User_id`, `User`.`name` AS `User_name`, `User`.`email` AS `User_email`, `User`.`password` AS `User_password`, `User`.`createdAt` AS `User_createdAt`, `User`.`updatedAt` AS `User_updatedAt` FROM `user` `User` WHERE `User`.`id` IN (?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: [5,7]
query: SELECT `User_followers_rid`.`userId_1` AS `userId_1`, `User_followers_rid`.`userId_2` AS `userId_2` FROM `user` `user` INNER JOIN `user_followers_user` `User_followers_rid` ON (`User_followers_rid`.`userId_1` = ? AND `User_followers_rid`.`userId_2` = `user`.`id`) OR (`User_followers_rid`.`userId_1` = ? AND `User_followers_rid`.`userId_2` = `user`.`id`)  ORDER BY `User_followers_rid`.`userId_2` ASC, `User_followers_rid`.`userId_1` ASC -- PARAMETERS: [5,7]
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO `user_followers_user`(`userId_1`, `userId_2`) VALUES (?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: [5,7]
query: DELETE FROM `user_followers_user` WHERE `userId_1` = ? AND `userId_2` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [5,6]
query: COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have this problem is that when you query user, you are not adding `followers` relation with it. Write a `console.log(user)` and you will see `user` object doesn't have `followers` attribute. That's why every time you call the api, it replaces the old one with new one.

You have to add `followers` relation in your query. This will return all the existing follower's list  in form of  `user.followers` of `User` object. Another thing you can use
`user.followers.push(userToFollow);` instead of `user.followers = [...(user?.followers || []), userToFollow];` in your code. Use the code below,

```js
try {
            let user = await userRepository.findOneOrFail(currentUserId, { relations: ["followers"] });
            let userToFollow = await userRepository.findOneOrFail(userToFollowId);

            if (user && userToFollow) {
                user.followers.push(userToFollow);
                await userRepository.save(user);
                return res.status(201).send("Followed");
            } else {
                throw new Error("User not found!")
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm :) I was wondering why am I getting undefined error when I try to use .push method on followers property, but now that too makes sense!